# make an array from a dynamic column in the middle of text

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

I need to know how many connection from an application is connected to my database. for that i should run an stored procedure. the output is like:

```
  CMD_EXEC: 1
  IFCA_RET: 0
  IFCA_RES: 0
  XS_BYTES: 0
  IFCA_GRES: 0
  GXS_BYTES: 0
  RETURN_CODE: 0
  MSG: NULL

  ROWNUM      TEXT
  1           DSNL200I  -DSNC DISPLAY LOCATION REPORT FOLLOWS-
  2           LOCATION                                       PRDID    T ATT CONNS
  3           ::170.0.0.236                                  SQL09079 S        277
  4           ::170.0.0.243                                  SQL10057 S          0
  5           ::170.0.0.249                                  JCC04160 S          0
  6           ::170.0.0.252                                  JCC03660 S          0
  7           ::170.0.0.204                                  JCC04160 S          0
  8           ::170.0.0.20                                   SQL10057 S          1
  9           ::170.0.0.21                                   JCC03660 S          0
  10          ::170.0.1.21                                   JCC04080 S       1440
  11          ::170.0.1.231                                  JCC03660 S          1
  12          ::170.0.7.2                                    JCC03640 S          0
  13          ::170.0.8.241                                  JCC03640 S          0
  14          ::170.0.8.142                                  JCC03690 S          0
  15          ::192.168.7.2                                  SQL09079 S          0
  16          ::192.168.1.4                                  JCC03650 S          5
  17          ::192.168.1.5                                  JCC03650 S          6
  18          ::192.168.1.0                                  JCC03690 S          0
  19          ::192.168.4.0                                  JCC03610 S          7
  20          ::192.168.4.0                                  JCC03610 S          2
  21          ::192.168.4.0                                  JCC04080 S        504
  22          ::192.168.1.7                                  SQL10055 S          1
  23          DISPLAY LOCATION REPORT COMPLETE

   "ADMIN_COMMAND_DB21" RETURN_STATUS: 0
```

the column `CONNS` shows the count of connections. i need to make an array with this column and find its max. for example something like this:

```
 #/bin/bash

 #number of logs to offload
 #number of ADBAT
 #number of QUEDBAT
 #number of DSCDBAT
 #nmber of connections

 DB2PATH=/home/db2inst1/sqllib/bin/db2

 $DB2PATH connect to mydb >> /dev/null
 conn_arr=$($DB2PATH "CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_COMMAND_DB21 ('-dis 
 location',17,LOC,NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"  )
 echo "$conn_arr" | ????
 $DB2PATH connect reset >> /dev/null
```

Every time this script the results and the row numbers change.  What should i use?

Comment: It strikes me as something you'd want to do in your database query, not in a shell script.

Comment: @Kusalananda actually there is a table in database that with a simple query you can get the result but that is for LUW(linux). this one is for mainframe(zos) and must be handled with shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the maximum number of connections and save the number in the variable `mx`, try:

```
$ mx=$(awk '/COMPLETE/{exit} f{if($5+0>x)x=$5} /CONNS/{f=1} END{print x}' <<<"$conn_arr")
$ echo $mx
1440
```

#### How it works

By default, awk reads through a file one line at a time.

- `/COMPLETE/{exit}`

  If the current line matches the regex `COMPLETE`, then stop reading any more lines and exit to the `END` command group.
- `f{if($5+0>x)x=$5}`

  If the variable `f` is true (nonzero), then if the number in column 5 is greater than the variable `x`, set `x` to the value in column 5.
- `/CONNS/{f=1}`

  If the current line contains the string (regex) `CONNS`, then set variable `f` to one.  This signals the start of the table.
- `END{print x}`

  After we have finished reading all the lines, print the value of `x`.
- `<<<"$conn_arr"`

  Tell awk to read its input from the bash variable `conn_arr`.  This construct is called a *here string*.

Comment: where should i add the path of my file or the variable that i redirected my SP output to?

Comment: @BlackCrystal In my code, I called that variable `conn_arr`.  Isn't that the same name that you used?

Comment: yes. didn't notice they are the same. WOW. your solution is so fast. in my main script i have a loop that do this for lots of databases and i got result in less than one second.thanks!